# Is there a way to require all fields be entered in order to avoid vector subscript out of range error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a database simulator coded in C++, and the way it works essentially is that the user says `"insert 'item' 'quantity' 'price'"` with `item` being a string and `quantity`/`price` being an int.

The issue I am running into is that whenever the user enters `"insert"` and doesn't put the other fields, a "vector subscript out of range" error pops up.

So, for example, `"insert keyboard 20"` would give me the error because no price was given.

I thought it was because the values are not originally initialized, but I tried to do that and nothing changed. I've tried initializing them in the structure to 0, but it still makes me abort the program. I imagine it's because the class I'm using is searching for 3 variables, and when it doesn't get them, it crashes.

I'm honestly not sure that there is a way to do this with my current code (I can't really completely overhaul it, they wanted classes), but I figured I'd take a shot in the dark with you tech gurus.

Below are the two classes that I am using.

The class that edits my created structure database:

```cpp
class ProductDB
{
public:
    ProductDB() = default;
    ~ProductDB() = default;

    //Commands to give ProductDB control over appending, removing, updating, finding, and printing 
    void append(const string& name, int quantity, double price);

private:
    vector<Product> items;
    //initialize sequence counter for append
    int seq = 0;

    //check for unique names using set function
    set<string> productNames;
};
```

And here is the class that inserts the information into the database:

```cpp
//class to append
void ProductDB::append(const string& name, int quantity, double price)
{
    if (quantity <= 0 || price <= 0) {
        cout << "Input Error: Please enter a quantity" << endl;
        return;
    }       

    if (productNames.find(name) != productNames.end()) {
        cout << "Input Error: That name already exists, Please enter an unique name!" << endl;
        return;
    }

    Product item;
    //running total for sequence
    item.id = ++seq;
    item.name = name;
    item.quantity = quantity;
    item.price = price;

    items.push_back(item);

    // insert name in database as the product gets inserted
    productNames.insert(name);
    cout << "Entry: '" << item.name << "' inserted successfully!" << endl;
}
```

And this is where I call to the class:

```cpp
//insert command 
if (cmdInput[0] == "insert")
{
    string name = cmdInput[1];
    int quantity = stoi(cmdInput[2]);
    double price = stod(cmdInput[3]);
    itemsDB.append(name, quantity, price);
}
```

Comment: Where did `cmdInput` get populated? That is the most relevant part. Basically before tokenizing that input you'd want to validate that it contained the right number of values for that command (e.g. `"insert"`)

Comment: for me it looks like you should use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` instead `std::set` and `std::vector`.

Comment: What is `cmdInput` declared as?  I'm assuming `vector<string>`? Where does the "subscript out of range" error actually come from? Because `vector::operator[]` does not perform bounds checking, so it is actually *undefined behavior* to access an element out of bounds (use `vector::at()` instead if you need bounds checking). But in any case, what is stopping you from simply checking `cmdInput.size() == 4` before trying to process the contents of `cmdInput`?

Comment: assuming `cmdInput` is command line argument you should use some library for parsing that. For example [boost::program_options](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/program_options.html). With this you can define proper program arguments and its requirements.

Comment: Ch3ster and ravenspoint answered it correctly. I wasn't familiar with input size coding yet, but thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
//insert command 
if (cmdInput[0] == "insert")
{
    if( (int)cmdInput.size() < 4 ) {
        std:cout << "Not enough input params\n";
}
else {
    string name = cmdInput[1];
    int quantity = stoi(cmdInput[2]);
    double price = stod(cmdInput[3]);
    itemsDB.append(name, quantity, price);
    }
}
```

This technique is called "firewalling": writing code that checks the input for correctness BEFORE starting to process the input.  This keeps all the messy if statements and error handling separate from the processing code which can proceed assuming everything is good and so can be coded in a clear straightforward manner, easily understood and maintained.